# How to optimize PhantomJS for search engines to index a single page application?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, htmlunit, single-page-application, headless-browser

I have been searching for an headless web browser that can run on server for web crawlers to index a single page application. Firslyt I tried HTMLUnit and Selenium (HtmlUnitDriver) but it seems both of them have issues with xhr requests.

And I discovered PhantomJS which performs better and seems mature. PhantomJS has an [internal webserver](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/) so I decided to use it with my reverse proxy. However I ran a benchmark and PhantomJS hits a cpu core 100% and the average page loading the is around 4 seconds. The reason is I have to wait the browser to load all resources to be able to get correct results. Here is my PhantomJS script:

```
var page = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var server = require('webserver').create();

// credit: http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/
var service = server.listen(port, { 'keepAlive': true }, function(z, response) {
    var request = page.create();
    var lastReceived = new Date().getTime();
    var requestCount = 0;
    var responseCount = 0;
    var requestIds = [];
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    request.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
        if (requestIds.indexOf(response.id) !== -1) {
            lastReceived = new Date().getTime();
            responseCount++;
            requestIds[requestIds.indexOf(response.id)] = null;
        }
    };
    request.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
        if (requestIds.indexOf(request.id) === -1) {
            requestIds.push(request.id);
            requestCount++;
        }
    };
    request.settings = { 
      loadImages: false, 
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      loadPlugins: false 
    };
    request.open(z.url, function (status, a) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address '+a);
        }
    });
    var checkComplete = function () {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if ((now - lastReceived > 300 && requestCount === responseCount) || now - startTime > 5000) {
            clearInterval(checkCompleteInterval);
            response.statusCode = 200;
            response.headers = {
                'Cache': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
                'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
                'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100',
                'Content-Length': request.content.length
            };
            response.write(request.content);
            response.close();
            request.release();
            console.log(request.url+" -> "+(now - startTime));
        }
    }
    var checkCompleteInterval = setInterval(checkComplete, 3);

});
```

Is there any improvement that can be done to speed up the script, should I just run PhantomJS using its shell command for better performance or is there any alternative to these browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some [command line switches](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) to improve the capture performance:

First, you can ignore all images with `--load-images=no`. There's no need to load images when doing the HTML snapshots.

You can also enable the cache with `--disk-cache=yes` (use `--max-disk-cache-size` to set its size in bytes)

Finally, the [`WebPage#onResourceRequested`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html) callback may also be useful to abort some requests (trackers, media files...) with the `NetworkRequest#abort` method.

Comment: hmm, I didn't see you already set loadImages to false so the first advice is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the NetworkRequest#abort tip. Facebook API and analytics APIs' are not necessary in this case and it seems the script is faster now.